# Force align div with the upper div

Tags: css, html

I'm creating a web but having trouble with the alignment of divs. Cant fix this problem for a day now.

How do I force align the image(the text image)? It's inside the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" charset="utf-8;" content="text/html" />



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>
<
```

And force the lower div to stay put when window resized or zoomed in/out.

Comment: Well, a good start would be to completely remove that image a use a `<p/>` tag

Comment: I tried removing it but still doesn't work.

Comment: Agree with Connor using an image for text like that is a really bad idea.

Comment: @yakults What's with all the DOCTYPEs and all the `<head>`s in your website?

Comment: @yakults No, I mean on your actual website, that you link to. You have three `<head>` elements, each with different `<title>`s. What is the browser supposed to do there, choose between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first issue is don't add specific margin like "margin-right:300px" when you want it to be resized or zoomed in/out.

and second issue is adding "float:right" to the image.

the below changes to the code will solve your problem.

```
<div style="width: 960px; margin:0 auto;" align="left">
   <p>
     <span style="float:left">
       <br>
       ABOUT CTI
     </span>
     <img src="images/about-cti.jpg"/>
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly well on FF and Chrome but no effect on IE 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you seriously want to use a "text image" as a regular image, why not use it in a style sheet? So right now you have it in a div, so make that div a class or id like  and make a style sheet where you have that image as a background image. Then you can use the position tactic to put the image wherever you want.

```
HTML:

<body>
      <div class="textimage">

      </div>
</body>


CSS:

.textimage{
width:500px;
height:500px;
background-image: url('..whatever.gif'); 
background-position: 50px 50px; //the first coordinate moves the image left to right // while the second coordinate moves it up and down
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <img style="width: 960px;" src="images/about us img.jpg"></img>
    <div style="text-align: center">
            <img src="images/about-cti.jpg"></img>
            <br />ABOUT CTI
    </div>
</div>
```